# Codeigniter Model loading error

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I had a working project uploaded to server 2 week before. It was working fine until now. Below is code for model      awsmodel.php

```
class Awsmodel extends MY_Model {

    function __construct()
    {

    }
    // some other functions
}
```

MY_Model again extends to CI_model.

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
// required functions
}
```

From controller pages.php I am calling the function like below.

```
class Pages extends MY_Controller {
  public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->allCommonMenu();
        $this->load->model('Awsmodel');
        $data['featured'] = $this->Awsmodel->featuredProp();
        $this->load->view('home_pz',$data);
    }
 }
```

The above code suddenly stooped working today. After some test and tries, I got to know that when I comment below 2 lines from controller function then The page loads.

```
  $this->load->model('Awsmodel');
  $data['featured'] = $this->Awsmodel->featuredProp();
```

I have changed environment variable to 'development' and tested but still no error message shows. In firefox its showing a blank page, where as in chrome it shows 500 server error. The same code was working since 2 weeks. Don't know why its not working now. If anyone can help me out ?
I am using CI version 2.1.4

Comment: Which version of CI you use???

Comment: you can also check your Apache error log for error!!

Comment: @Saty Sorry my mistake - its CI version 2.1.4

Comment: set display_errors value 'On' in your php.ini and set log_threshold = 4 ,log_path = 'application/logs/' in your CI config.php to get error on page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using CI 3.0 please load model like this

```
class Pages extends MY_Controller {
  public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->allCommonMenu();
        $this->load->model('awsmodel'); //as your model filename: awsmodel.php
        $data['featured'] = $this->Awsmodel->featuredProp();
        //$data['featured'] = $this->awsmodel->featuredProp();// for  CI version 2.1.4 –
        $this->load->view('home_pz',$data);
    }
 }
```